# Python ctypes: How do I flush output from stderr?

Tags: python, windows, dll, ctypes

I've written some function callbacks using python's ctypes to access functions in a DLL.  The code used to build that DLL has some debugging print statements in it using fprintf to stderr.  However, when I run my python code, I don't see that output to stderr consistently.  Only rarely I will see it flush the output from stderr to the console that I'm using.  I've tried running it with "python -u foo.py", but that doesn't help either.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's all the same stderr.

```
sys.stderr.flush()
```

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid.  I had tried using sys.stderr.flush(), but I put it in a spot that was never reached.  Thanks for the swift response!